# Why doesn't the last line of the child process print?

Tags: c, fork, exit, wexitstatus

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main( ) {
    pid_t pid;
    int status = -1; 

    if ((pid = fork()) != 0) {
       printf("Father process wait child PID=%d\n", pid);
       wait(&status);
       printf("Child finish with status: %d\n",WEXITSTATUS(status));
       exit(0);
    }
    else {
       printf("Child process running...\n");
       execl("/bin/ls","ls", "-la", NULL);
       printf("Child ending...\n");
    }
}
```

When compiling this code the last line of the else doesn't print and I don't know why.

Comment: Did you actually read the man page for `execl`? It tells you all you need to know - it does not return on success.

Answer (score 3):

http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.
>   ....
>
> **Return Value**
>
> The exec() functions only return if an error has occurred. The return
>   value is -1, and errno is set to indicate the error.